# access docmd.openform text complex criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, criteria

Here is the code that is not working for me:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm8SerialsByModel", acFormDS,,"[Serial Number] like '" & Me.txtserialap & "' or like '*" & Me.txtserialap & "' or like '" & Me.txtserialap & "*' or like '*" & Me.txtserialap & "*'"
```

Regardless the following works perfectly in query criteria:

```
Like [Forms]![frm8Serials]![txtserialap] Or 
Like "*" & [Forms]![frm8Serials]![txtserialap] Or 
Like [Forms]![frm8Serials]![txtserialap] & "*" Or 
Like "*" & [Forms]![frm8Serials]![txtserialap] & "*"
```

So I know that the question was most probably asked before, so I would like to ask you to recommend an article with a proper explanation of punctuation on writing string criteria containing different types of data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this your actual code, or just something you typed up?  If it's real, then why compare to the same field 4 times?  Also, what value is in txtseriallap? Using 'LIKE' should have an asterisk in one or two places. Plus where is the first "&" between "like '" Me"  (i.e. "like '" & Me"

Comment: Dear Wayne, thank you for your rapid answer. There are serial numbers in the field which is text (715PNZB23237). Reason to compare multiple times is to display all the serial numbers that have the searched text in the beginning, inside and in the end of the values. Please correct me if there is an easier way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat the *WhereCondition* argument in [DoCmd.OpenForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openform-method-access) as any `WHERE` clause in SQL. Therefore, your field, *Serial Number*, needs to be repeated for each condition. And first `LIKE` is redundant as it uses no wildcards so can be replaced with equality `=`:

```
strfilter = "[Serial Number] = '" Me.txtserialap & "'" & _
            " OR [Serial Number] LIKE '*" & Me.txtserialap & "'" & _
            " OR [Serial Number] LIKE '" & Me.txtserialap & "*'" & _
            " OR [Serial Number] LIKE '*" & Me.txtserialap & "*'"

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm8SerialsByModel", acFormDS, ,strfilter
```

Comment: With `OR [Serial Number] LIKE '*" & Me.txtserialap & "*'"` in there, the 3 other criteria are redundant and could be removed.

Comment: Thanks Andre and Parfait. That is very useful to know!

Comment: FYI the original post did not include any wildcards, so depending on when you saw this post ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Wayne G. Dunn. So as you suggested I don't need to compare it 3 times, the following is enough for my purpose and it works:
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm8SerialsByModel", acFormDS, , "[Serial Number] like '*" & Me.txtserialap & "*'"

Still, I will be very grateful if you suggest any resources to read about complex criteria in VBA. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, the single compare will work as long as you are certain there can be no false returns due to a character pattern repeating in your string. i.e. if you want to find a "57" car and your data looks like "55 Chevy was purchased by my 57 year old aunt". As for resources, I have always found it easiest to just use the query builder to create the SQL, then tweak as necessary (I'm lazy and a lousy typist!) Also, Google is your friend: try "access vba create complex query" (without the quotes).  Good luck!